# Java: Get delimeters in a string in the same order it appeared

Tags: java, regex

I am planning to split a string which is composed of numbers and operators (eg. +,-,*,/) and store the numbers in an array and also store the operators in an array. I have managed to get the numbers and store them in an array with this code

```
String num = "58.5+98*78/96/78.7-3443*12-3";
String[] strings = (num.split("[+|*|/|-]"));
for (String string : strings) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

*Which outputs:*

- 58.5
- 98
- 78
- 96
- 78.7
- 3443
- 12
- 3

*What I want to do/have is get the delimiters in the same order they appeared on the string, like this:*

- +
- *
- /
- /
- -
- *
- -

I know this has something to do with **regex** but I am having a hard time implementing it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: if you also need the value of the captured match you need to use a proper regex class and not just `String.split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something quick and dirty you can split using the negated regex and ignore/remove the empty strings.

```
String strings = (num.split("[^+|*|/|-]"));
for (String string : strings) {
    if (!string.equals("")) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked! really Don't know much bout regex, thanks for your help!!